# What does a capacitor do in a tesla coil?

Tags: capacitor, tesla-coil

I just can't seem to understand what a capacitor does in a tesla coil. Could somebody explain what the capacitor does? I'm new to this kind of thing, so could you write it in a moron friendly way?

Comment: The capacitor[s] together with the transformer[s] create a [resonant LC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit#Operation). To be more precise it's [a dual-resonant circuit](http://makezine.com/projects/make-35/six-pack-tesla-coil/), i.e. you have two tanks. Whether you will understand this explanation or not... depends on your background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tesla coil is a resonant transformer. The key to making them work is to generate a lot of power at a particular frequency to drive the primary side of the transformer. The basic way of doing this is to take a bunch of energy and dump it into an LC circuit. The LC circuit is made up of an inductor (L) and capacitor (C) in series and has a natural resonant frequency determined by the value of L and C. When you dump a bunch of energy into an LC circuit it wants to oscillate at it's resonant frequency. This generates the frequencies needed to drive the coil. So, to answer your question, the capacitor makes up half the LC circuit which generates the frequencies that drive the coil.